# how to find DataDog synthetic tests location for current test run

Tags: automated-tests, datadog, synthetic

We have the same test running concurrently in different locations, currently the tests re-use a single user and the problem is they cannot be logged in in both locations at the same time. We would like to have an alternative user used when the location of the test run is non default.

So we are trying to find the way to identify the location used for execution in the UI synthetic test, so we can swap out the variable for the username/password at runtime.

Has anyone got any advice on how to achieve this? I was hoping there would be some standard run configuration settings populated that we could query, but can't find any documentation about them?